# When I am creating record and saving manually record number is generated but record number is not generated using selinium automation

Tags: selenium, automation

The task is that when I create a record and click save then verify using automation that a record number is generated automatically.

However when I am executing this task manually and saving it record number is generated but when I am creating the same record with same fields using automation then record number is not generated.

Ways I tried:

1. I have tried pausing selenium after clicking save button but I am not able to figure out the reason.
2. I have checked that user is the same manually and through automation.
   What else I could be the reason

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

i believe you have to replicate user action while saving the record instead of performing an action on DOM. you can give a try using any of the below options
1) Actions Class
2)Robot Class
3)Sikuli